# providing a java servlet with information

Tags: c#, java, servlets

i am new to servlets. I made a simple hello world programme that prints those famous 2 words to the screen when i access the page via a browser using http://localhost:8080/mypath/path...

My question is now, how do i provide a servlet with information? Specifically considering the fact that my c# programme calculates a lookup value for a global system, then the "java" servlet processes that and returns a set of results.

I have done the reverse thanks to help on here, regarding calling a returned string from the java servlet in c#. However i am not sure how i go about providing the servlet information. Do i pass it via the url?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that you wish to pass information **to** servlet you can do it:

- using request parameters (for example url arguments if you use GET method)
- by parsing request URL (see HttpServletRequest.getRequestURL() and getRequestURI())
- by examining the HTTP headers and cookies (see HttpServletRequest.getHeaders() )

If you are asking about sending information from servlet back to client you can write it into output stream got from `HttpServletResponse`.